# Generate code and test coverage report separately without running coverage run twice

Tags: coverage.py

I am running coverage,py tool to get code coverage. Using command,

```
     COVERAGE_FILE=.coverage_dir coverage run -a --omit */tests/* ./manage.py test --settings=dir.tests.settings_unittest
```

I can view reports using, coverage report --data-file=.coverage_dir

This gives me coverage report of python source files. If I don't omit tests, I will get coverage report for both source and test files.

I want to have separate tests and code coverage report. If it is possible that I have to run the command only once.

So that in the end I can just run

```
coverage report --data-file=.coverage_dir
coverage report --data-file=.coverage_test
```

to view the reports and get html reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `--include` option on the report command.  Use `coverage run` once without the `--omit` option, then:

```
coverage report --include='tests/*'
coverage report --include='the_product/*'
```